# rabbitmq-server : Depends: socat but it is not going to be installed. Cannot install rabbitMQ

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

I have been trying now for a few hours to install rabbitMQ on my linux VM.
I am currently running:

```
Linux 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64
<pre>Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

I am following the instructions specified on [rabbitMQ page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt)

After running sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server I receive the title error. Can someone confirm that there is no support for version 18.10 cosmic? That is the only thing I can think of that might explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I was correct. I had to downgrade the version of Ubuntu I was using from 18.10 to 18.04.